# MVC BaseController Unit Testing Coverage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

This is a best practice question. All my controllers do the same things with the only difference being in the repositories and queries that are specific to each so all the CRUD actions are in a BaseController with overrides for the specific controllers as needed.

So my question is, if I pick one derived controller and unit test all the actions, can I safely assume the other derived controllers are good, or should I still test each and every controller?

**Edit:**

Here's an example to make it clearer what's taking place, and I'm fine with whatever is the best practice, I'm just making sure I'm finding the right balance between thorough testing and testing myself to death. The example below just shows one short action to keep the example small, but the BaseController also handles Create, CreatePost, Edit, EditPost, and Delete.

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntity> : Controller where TEntity : class
{
    public BaseController()
    { }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        TEntity entity = await DetailsQueryAsync(id);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(entity)
    }

    protected virtual Task<TEntity> DetailsQueryAsync(int? id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class StudentsController : BaseController<Student>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Student> studentRepository;

    public StudentsController(UnitOfWork<SchoolContext> unitOfWork)
        : base()
    {
        studentRepository = unitOfWork.StudentRepository;
    }

    protected override async Task<Student> DetailsQueryAsync(int? id)
    {
        return await studentRepository.Get(id.Value)
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you test just 1 drived controller and leave the rest untested.... later in the future if more code needs to be written in other drived controllers .... then you will have to REMEMBER to write unit test for those controllers... Hope this make sense.

Comment: It does, it sounds like I can fall in a trap where I'll only be looking at common functions and if project requirements change, I'll forget to unit test any unique functions.

Comment: You didn't mention it but I would strongly recommend that you design to interfaces and inject an object to provide DetailsQueryAsync.  Then you can unit test your controller and the code you have in it for adherence to the interfaces it supports.  Your classes a coupled and will be hard to test in a large system.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns interesting, I love when people give me food for thought to go learn more. Do you have any examples I could start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question - no, I don't think testing one derived class of a base class constitutes code coverage.

But if the code in your controllers is merely making data access calls, I don't think its worth bothering unit testing them.

Comment: Please see my edit above, you may still be right but I just wanted to make sure it was clear what I'm doing. My goal is thorough enough testing for pre-release QA and to help with regression testing, but also to not "beat a dead horse" with redundant tests.